# Opening a public folder item via code and confusion about ids

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

After some reading I'm beginning to understand that there are multiple formats for the various ids used in exchange and Outlook.  I'm trying to clear up some confusion, here is the scenario.

We have a vendor product that is crawling public folder content in Exchange server and identifying messages that meet certain criteria.  When this software captures each message it stores an id that looks similar to the following:

```
AAIARgAAAAAAGkRzkKpmEc2byACqAC/EWgkAzDDxpv7lakqqtxgSLYsXTwAAAoOedgAA+v7vRoYnskqzbHwT4KwucwAAIH9adQAALgAAAAAAGkRzkKpmEc2byACqAC/EWgMAzDDxpv7lakqqtxgSLYsXTwAAAoOedgAA
```

I'm responsible for writing a WinForms application that presents these messages in a list and among other things allows them to open the message in Outlook.  For purposes of this question, you may assume the user has access to the message.

In looking through the Outlook API and inspecting the message properties it looks like the only id I can find there takes the form:

```
000000001A447390AA6611CD9BC800AA002FC45A0900CC30F1A6FEE56A4AAAB718122D8B174F000002839E760000FAFEEF468627B24AB36C7C13E0AC2E730000207F5A750000
```

I've read material that suggests these could be the same id expressed in different formats but have had no luck using the `ConvertId` operation in the EWS services.

Can anyone confirm whether these are truly different representations of the same id or completely different entities?  And whether it is possible to get from one to the other?

Answer (score 0):

These are not the same ids - they are different ids referring to the same object.
If you are having problems with the ConvertId EWS separation, you might want to post a separate ConvertId specific question.